# maven when to use clean over compile

Tags: maven

When running `mvn clean install`

It will clean target directory, compile and run tests.

However it does not run any of the clean options unless its explicitly stated? e.g.  this will not clean the target directory

`mvn install`

So I often run clean just to be sure its always fresh.

If I make a code change do I need to always clean if wanting to verify the new code changes?.

`compile` is part of the default life cycle which runs when I type `mvn install` doesnt this do the same thing?  Whats the main benefit of clean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `clean` goal removes any of the output files located in `target/` or wherever else you've specified them.

Incremental compilation is a thing in Maven - which is why other goals don't automatically assume `clean` - but it is often considered to be unreliable at best.  For sanity's sake, it is best to always `clean` your workspace so that you don't get bizarre class collisions.

Comment: Incremental compilation is usually faster.  I don't normally clean my workspace when making changes unless I see odd behavior - just remember you are not cleaning and make doing a clean build your first step in trouble shooting.  I do run a clean build after finishing my changes as a final check.

Comment: @Blair:  That kind of plays into my point about incremental building in Maven being unreliable, since you do run into odd behavior when building.

Comment: what makes compiling unreliable? seems a bit of a sweeping statement?  Just trying to figure out when clean is necessary.

Comment: @Robbo_UK:  I'd recommend that you always clean your builds to ensure that you're building what you think you are.  There's other literature on the Internet about how incremental builds in Maven are broken to an extent, and I would do those sources a disservice to repeat it here.

Answer (score 1):

**clean** command clean your target (your projects build location).

**install** command build your package and put it into your maven local repository also thats why other project can use your projects as library from maven local repository.

and **compile** just compile the source code of the project.

So If you use **mvn clean install** it will first clean your build directory then compile your project and build target directory with compiled files and then put it into your maven local repository. So you can use your projects files to others project from your maven local repository.

and **mvn clean compile** will first clean your build directory and then compile your project and build target directory with compiled files